# Multiple annotation in JSP page

Tags: maven, jsp

I am developing a JSP page in Maven application. In that page while trying to add a datalist tag it's showing the following error as in the image.

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg3sp.png)

Please help... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please don't post the image .Post the code

Comment: For datalist part of  HTML5 use `<!DOCTYPE html>`  this tag instead of html4

Comment: @soorapadman Sorry for that. here is my code

Comment: where it is your code?